# Core Data: Fetch Crashes When Moving to Detail View

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest

My app is multiview. The master view leads to a detail view with Core Data things. When I try pressing a button in the master view to go to the detail view, I get the following crash:

```
2010-11-21 01:41:01.487 CustomTableView[2253:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'
```

The Core Data code used to work fine in another project but it crashes in this one.
Views without Core Data have no problems

How can I fix this?
Any help is appreciated

---

**Update**

Here's the fetch code:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


CustomTableViewAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Hero" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

Answer (score 0):

The fetch request doesn't have its entity specified. Code like this is missing:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

Or, if you're using a fetch request template, the template is missing its Entity specifier.

Comment: Yeah I have that kind of code in my fetchresultcontroller method, this method is in the view that has core data, do I need to relocate it somewhere else?

Comment: Can you verify that the entity being used for the fetch request is non-nil? Perhaps the entity name is misspelled or the managed object context is nil.

Comment: The entity name is the same, but I am not sure about manage object context, let me recheck first

Comment: by the way, is there any other factors that can cause this situation to happen?

Comment: Not that I know of. The error message states that "a fetch request must have an entity." That's a pretty clear indication that the fetch request used in your `CustomTableView` is lacking an entity. Logging the entity—`NSLog(@"%@", entity);`—should be able to confirm or discount this.

Comment: NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


CustomTableViewAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Hero" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
here's what I have, did I do something wrong? My xcdatamodel file only has one entity Hero

Comment: Either your managed object context is `nil`, you don't have an entity named "Hero", or your model wasn't correctly loaded. My suggestion is to check your application delegate code.

Comment: My manage object context is not nil and I have an entity by the name Hero, so I think the only left is the last one. The main page is multi view and the core data page is navigation control, is this the reason why I crashed? If so, can you point out some way I can fix this? Thanks very much

Comment: I recommend rereading Apple's Core Data Programming Guide, especially the section on managed object models. You say that the entity is (null), so your problem comes before the fetch request—probably in your model, managed object context, or entity name. Perhaps the persistent store coordinator isn't being initialized with the correct model. The debugger should help you find where things might be going wrong. Good luck!